# how to open multiple view of same JavaScript (.js) file with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Anyone know how to open multiple windows of the same Visual Studio 2010 Javascript or Visual Basic file, like you can with a .c or .cpp or .h or .txt file?

Visual Studio can open multiple view of a 'C' .c file, but not a VisualBasic or .js file, becuase the Window menu, 'New Window' command is dimmed out when VisualBAsic or JavaScript files are selected.

YET!  Just now, somehow, I have two view of the same JavaScript file open, but I don't know how I did it.  Some combination of click-and-drag and a keyboard button, I think.

(I wish Bill Gates would take a break from nuking around and return to Microsoft for a while -- they've been like a chicken with its head cut off since he left.)

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy towards others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Window -> Split, you'll get two views of the same file...